# jQuery Scroll Box Without Scrollbar

Tags: jquery, scrollbar

I have a box that is 250px x 250px. I want to make it scrollable, but I don't want to have the scrollbars appear because of how much space they take up. I assume this is possible with jQuery, but not finding anything. Anyone know?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can put what you want to scroll inside a another div, whose size is set. And make the css of this container to `overflow: hidden;` so there are no scroll bars. Then you can create some triggers (click on up/down arrows, etc.) that trigger a scrollTo on the container div.

Here's an example:
http://jsfiddle.net/UwEe2/

Comment: I will try that, thanks! Basically all I want is for them to be able to scroll it up and down only by hovering over the box and using the mouse or track pad to scroll.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work on the root scrollable element (in some browsers it's the body element, in others the html element).

Answer (score 0):

Found a nice script: [jQuery slimScroll](http://rocha.la/jQuery-slimScroll), solving your problem while looking awesome. (not my script)